# Amsterdam to Dublin with Ryanair for unvaccinated

Tags: covid-19, ireland, amsterdam, dublin, bulgarian-citizens

My friend, who is from Bulgaria, is planning to go to Dublin from Amsterdam. He is not vaccinated, so what are the rules for him?

Comment: Just note that as far as I was able to find, vaccines are available in Bulgaria, so the country has little to do with friend being unvaccinated and it would be unfair to blame it.

Comment: I assume said 'friend' lives in the Netherlands, but even there getting vaccinated should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your friend must complete a ‘Passenger Locator Form" at most 72 hours before arrival and have proof of a negative RT-PCR test taken no more than 72 hours before his arrival in Ireland.

He will not have to quarantine when he arrives in Ireland but should follow public health advice if he develops symptoms of COVID-19 or if he is a close contact of a confirmed case of COVID-19.

Source: https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/travel_and_recreation/travel_to_ireland/travel_to_ireland_during_covid.html

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to ask what the requirements are, I find the following resource invaluable for travel during COVID:

https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php

A quick scan of the information for Ireland seems to say that currently (updated today), a recent negative PCR test is sufficient. (As well as filling in a passenger locater form.)